# Firebase Cloud Messaging - Error when registering service working (...ServiceWorker script evaluation failed)

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I'm trying to setup up web notifications with FCM and I get error messages when trying to register the service worker.

My structure is as follows:

domain.com/notification/index.html

domain.com/notification/test-worker.js

Index.html:

```
function registerServiceWorker() 
{
    console.log('start register');
    return navigator.serviceWorker.register('/notification/test-worker.js')
    .then(function(registration) 
        {
            console.log('Service worker successfully registered.');
            askPermission();
            return registration;
        })
    .catch(function(err) 
        {
            console.error('Unable to register service worker.', err);
        });
    console.log('end register');
}
```

test-worker.js

```
 import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-app.js";
 import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-analytics.js";

 const messaging = getMessaging();
 onBackgroundMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
   console.log(' Received background message ', payload);
   // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
   body: 'Background Message body.'
 };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
   notificationOptions);
});
```

The errors I get are:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
Unable to register service worker. TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://example.com/notification/') with script ('https://example.com/notification/test-worker.js'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed
```

I understand that import cannot be used outside of a module but how can I specify that the service worker should be a module? I have seen many examples of service workers using import so I guess it should be possible to use import. Or should I use a different method?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fought with this same issue for a while. Lots of searching, trial and error later. I figured out that you have to register your service worker as a module.

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js', { type: 'module' });
```

After that you should be able to call the import from your file.

Comment: thanks, I'm sure it will help many people in the same situation!

Answer (score 0):

This is something very weird for me too. I tried chasing MIME type of service worker also but no luck. It looks there are no more good resources to use version 9 with service workers. I have to migrate a project to latest version, but I still have to keep compact libraries.

However, there is a method to load SW as a module, it is not safe for production level. Hope someone will answer this thread.

Comment: This answer lacks solution! Please try to keep these sorts of replies in comments, as otherwise it clutters the answer board.

Comment: yes indeed, I also reverted back to a previous version until I find a suitable solution with modules.

Comment: Inside SW, I just use V8 but for other pages V9 works. Wish you all the best!